Which is the difference between a Parallel.ForEach and a normal for that calls an async method that I don't wait?
Suppose I have these three versions of one class:
public MainClass
{
    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        foreach(OtherClass iterator in _otherClasses)
        {
            iterator.AnAsyncTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}



public MainClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(_list, async iterator =>
        {
            await iterator.AnAsyncTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
        });
    }
}


public MainClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(_list, iterator =>
        {
            iterator.AnAsyncTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
        });
    }
}

In the first one, I have a foreach that call an async method but I don't wait it finish to continue the next item, so in practice, is not the same than run various items in parallel with a parallel ForEach?
In the second one I have a Parallel ForEach, so it runs in parallel various items at the same time.
No matter if I wait or not, this only matters if I would need to do more after the method is finished inside the same iteration.
So my doubt is, which is the difference between to use ForEach or Parallel.Foreach in this case?
EDIT: a user suggest this question: but it is not really the same. I wanted to know the behaviour of an async method inside a foreach. The question you mention is the difference between the two kind of loops, no matter the code inside them.


foreach(OtherClass iterator in _otherClasses)
{
    iterator.AnAsyncTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
}


Behavior: The tasks are created sequentially, the one after the other. In case the AnAsyncTask fails synchronously, the loop will break with an exception.

Parallel.ForEach(_list, async iterator =>
{
    await iterator.AnAsyncTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
});


Behavior: The tasks are created in parallel. Multiple tasks are created at the same time. The degree of parallelism is set to unlimited (the default), so the only thing that will limit the parallelization of the task-creation is the ThreadPool availability. Regarding the asynchronous execution of the tasks, no concurrency limit is imposed whatsoever. In case the AnAsyncTask fails synchronously, an unhandled exception will be raised on the captured SynchronizationContext, resulting most likely in the crashing of the process. This happens because the Parallel.ForEach is not async friendly, so the async delegate is async void (which is something to avoid).

Parallel.ForEach(_list, iterator =>
{
    iterator.AnAsyncTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
});


Behavior: Everything the same as previously, with the exception that in case the AnAsyncTask fails synchronously, the loop will break with an AggregateException. This is an exception that you can catch, as opposed to the previous async void approach where the exception was unhandled and uncatchable.

Side note: In all three cases the .ConfigureAwait(false) is an artifact with absolutely no effect. You could change it to .ConfigureAwait(true), or remove it, and the behavior would be exactly the same.

In the first case the tasks are create sequencely, but they don't wait to finish one to create the next. So in practice isn't it like parallel execution?

@ÁlvaroGarcía yes, it falls within the general and broad definition of parallelism. There is a stricter definition though, according to which the tasks are only concurrent, and they are not parallel unless they represent CPU-bound work running on a multi-core machine. See this question for more details.
